# Data points not shown when using TikZ datavisualization in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-datavisualization

When I try to implement the first example of section 75.2 from the TikZ 3.0.0 manual within beamer I don't get any data points.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}                           
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
    visualize as smooth line]
  data {
    x, y
    -1.5, 2.25
    -1, 1
    -.5, .25
    0, 0
    .5, .25
    1, 1
    1.5, 2.25
  };                               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: in beamer]

whereas using the document class article and no frames yields the correct result.

Using the additional TikZ library `datavisualization.formats.functions` and the data block

```
data [format=function] {
var x : interval [-1.5:1.5] samples 7;
func y = \value x*\value x;
};
```

from the second example within section 75.2 from the TikZ 3.0.0 manual also yields the correct result, within article as well as within beamer document class.

Why is that and what can I do in order to be able to use the data structure as in the first example within beamer class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's reading the data `verbatim` so it sees the line ends, so you need `[fragile]` on the frame

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}                           
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
    visualize as smooth line]
  data {
    x, y
    -1.5, 2.25
    -1, 1
    -.5, .25
    0, 0
    .5, .25
    1, 1
    1.5, 2.25
  };                               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```